# Run kubernetes health check from inside container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Kubernetes liveness and readiness probes appear to run from outside the container via the kubelet. In Docker, health checks were run from inside the container.

For our use case, we need the health check to run from inside the container in a k8s environment to check a URL. How is this achieved via kubernetes?

I tried likeness and readiness probes but since they are run externally, they do not have the same environment needed to conduct the check.

Comment: You've tried *command* liveness/readiness checks not http ones?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no, can you link me please? Do those run inside the container? Thanks!!

Comment: you can check https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/ @JonTran

Comment: Yes, exec probes run in the container. So, can you clarify what you meant by "appear to run outside"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Normally, K8s is the orchestrator and makes decisions about the POD lifecycle. Your application returns its health to the K8s, and it restarts the POD.

If you want to achieve another behaviour, like terminating (gracefully shutdown) the application in specific cases - you can do it by adding additional logic to your entry point.

As mentioned in the comments, you can perform health/liveness checks using HTTP or command, as stated in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).